# Exporting 3D object with included animation as one single file

Tags: export

I would like to export a 3D object with its full animation in one single file, so
that it can be opened in After Effects.


So far it works, when I just export my 3D object to After Effects as an .obj, there it can be rotated and so on.
But to export it with the included animation, I couldn't figure out how to do that.


Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem, with or without an workaround (if there is no solution directly in blender)?

Comment: If After Effects supports FBX import you can export that from Blender.

Comment: Have you tried .fbx format?
Not promising anything, but might be worth a try

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but .fbx files can not imported into the beta version of After Effects. If i would bake the animation into an .obj file and then open it from after effects i would need an additional plugin like Element3D from VideoCopilot (which costs round about 200$).